# Find the biggest rectangular area consisting only of 2 types of letter in a given MxN board

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

Possible duplicate: [find largest submatrix algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301733)

---

I need help with a problem.

Given a `MxN` board represented with `M` letters (a-z) in each of the `N` lines, i have to find the biggest area in which there are only 2 types of letters in it. The area must have rectangular shape. Here's an example :

```
4x4:

AAAA
ABBC
BBCA
DCAA
```

The output will be 6, because the biggest rectangular area in which there are only 2 types of letters is in the upper corner AAA-ABB, there are only A and B (2 types).

Comment: Is this homework? Also, how efficient must it be? An exhaustive search will solve it, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: If you think that the algorithm will solve it, just post it, i'll see and decide if it'll work.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem though.

Comment: since this is (tagged) homework, maybe you can first explain what you have tried yourself, what problems you encountered, instead of just posting your assignment.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, i posted it here because I have no ideas of solving it. The only thing that comes to my mind is using some kind of bruteforce but i guess that'd be too heavy. Any ideas ?

Comment: @ggg: The people on SO generally don't like to do your homework for you. The reason is not that we don't like you, the reason is that you might end up as one of our co-workers. Until then we want you to learn as much as possible. The way to get your problem solved is to start thinking, get started, and come back here when you run into a dead end, explaining what you got so far and where you got stuck. Then we'd love to nudge you into the right direction.

Comment: Consider getting it working with brute force, then adding optimizations like caching. Maybe find the member letters of each rectangle my unioning the member letters of two smaller, known rectangles. It is difficult to give an answer without knowing some restrictions (how much memory you can use, how fast it has to be, etc.).

Comment: What is the goal of this assignment? What topics has your professor been covering in lecture? What have you been reading in your textbook? There's usually a big hint in there. Often there's even algorithm pseudo-code.

Comment: @sbi: You don't have to SOLVE IT for me, i want to get some ideas by more experienced people (don't tell me you haven't asked anything in your whole life?).
And don't worry, I won't become your co-worker - I've got cancer so I don't expect to live that much.

Comment: Urgent?  is there a ticking time bomb in the largest such rectangle in an M * N matrix?  A cancerous tumor?  Will a nuclear reactor melt down if this problem is not solved?

Many of us develop and support systems that are real-world life is reliant on. That you got a late start on you homework does not represent an urgent problem.

Comment: Are there any performance requirements or similar? Brute-forcing it should be fairly easy after all. For a more efficient approach, I'd experiment with some kind of dynamic programming. Start with the smallest possible rectangles, and then gradually try to combine them to yield larger (valid) rectangles. But honestly, unless there are any specific performance or time complexity requirements, I'd just brute force it.

Comment: Do you know an O(M*N) dynamic programming solution for finding the largest rectangle containing only a specific known set of characters? If not, then you probably shouldn't bother with this problem until you've solved that one. If so, then it's easily adapted to an O(M*N) solution to this problem - simply run it 26*25 times and take the best answer. I think it's also (but less easily) adapted into an O(M*N) solution with a much lower constant, but what I have in mind is kind of fiddly and I haven't tried to prove it works. It involves recording 4 or so "interesting rectangles" per cell.

Comment: And btw, are you in the same class as user kalbosh (http://stackoverflow.com/users/277585/kalbosh), or is it just the time of year for this kind of problem in different universities?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. I think you will have to do an exhaustive search.  However, once you have found a rectangle of area A that fits the criteria, there is no need to look at rectangles of any area less than A.
2. Any rectangle of size 2x2 or 1x3 that contains at least 3 different letters cannot be part of the solution.  Perhaps you could "tag" those areas first, and then do a second scan through the input, only considering rectangles not including those tagged areas.
3. Find a 1x1 rectangle that fits the criteria (i.e., every cell).  See if this rectangle can be expanded in one direction or the other and still fit the criteria.  Continue until it cannot be expanded in either direction and still fit the criteria.  There may be cases where the rectangle can be expanded in either direction: you will need to backtrack to check those cases (in your example, the 2x2 in the upper left can be expanded in either direction).  This sounds like a search problem to me -- read up on some search techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete working solution, but a possible direction to solving this problem:

Try representing the board in terms of *connected regions*, each region representing one or more connected locations containing the same letter. Then try to combine the regions.