# How to calculate Sub matrix of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, submatrix

I was giving a test for a company called Code Nation and came across this question which asked me to calculate how many times a number k appears in the submatrix M[n][n]. Now there was a example which said Input like this.

```
5
1 2 3 2 5
36
```

`M[i][j]` is to calculated by `a[i]*a[j]` 
which on calculation turn I could calculate.

```
1,2,3,2,5
2,4,6,4,10
3,6,9,6,15
2,4,6,4,10
5,10,15,10,25
```

Now I had to calculate how many times 36 appears in sub matrix of M.

The answer was 5.

**I am unable to comprehend how to calculate this submatrix. How to represent it?**
I had a naïve approach which resulted in many matrices of which I think none are correct.

One of them is Submatrix[i][j]

```
1 2 3  2  5
3 9 18 24 39
6 18 36 60 99
15 33 69 129 228
33 66 129 258 486
```

This was formed by adding all the numbers before it 0,0 to i,j

In this 36 did not appear 5 times so i know this is incorrect. If you can back it up with some pseudo code it will be icing on the cake.

Appreciate the help

[Edit] : Referred Following [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643908/getting-the-submatrix-with-maximum-sum) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814040/finding-the-maximum-sum-sub-rectangle-within-a-matrix?lq=1)

Comment: This question is poorly constructed. Consider stating the problem clearly and then separately describing your approach

Comment: @javadba i altered the question. Can you suggest any more improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have to compute how many submatrices of M have sum equal to 36.

Here is Matlab code:

```
a=[1,2,3,2,5];
n=length(a);
M=a'*a;
count = 0;
for a0 = 1:n
    for b0 = 1:n
        for a1 = a0:n
            for b1 = b0:n
                A = M(a0:a1,b0:b1);
                if (sum(A(:))==36)
                    count = count + 1;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
count
```

This prints out 5.

So you are correctly computing M, but then you have to consider every submatrix of M, for example, M is

```
1,2,3,2,5
2,4,6,4,10
3,6,9,6,15
2,4,6,4,10
5,10,15,10,25
```

so one possible submatrix is

```
1,2,3
2,4,6
3,6,9
```

and if you add up all of these, then the sum is equal to 36.

There is an [answer on cstheory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/number-of-submatrices-with-a-particular-sum) which gives an O(n^3) algorithm for this.

Comment: The pseudocode I gave is O(n^6) (looks at O(n^4) submatrices, and each submatrix has O(n^2) elements), but the method in the linked answer is O(n^3).

Comment: The algorithm in the [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/number-of-submatrices-with-a-particular-sum/) is not very intuitive can you give a pseudo code to explain it better