# how to find the maximum L sum in a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming

here is another dynamic programming problem that find the maximum L(chess horse - 4 item) sum in the given matrix (m x n)

For example :

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

L : (1,2,3,6), (1,4,5,6), (1,2,5,8), (4,5,6,9) ...

and the biggest sum is sum(L) = sum(7,8,9,6) = 30

what is the O(complexity) of the optimal solution ?

it looks like this [problem (submatrix with maximum sum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643908/getting-the-submatrix-with-maximum-sum)

1. Say all items are positive
2. Both positive and negative

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? It might be helpful if you provide some context.

Comment: @MAK it comes to my mind :) I have also hard version of it. I'm working on and will post in a few days. I don't know maybe there is a problem like that on the web

Comment: @Saeed 1. say positive 2. both(+ and -). I'm now editing

Comment: @hilal are all the rows in the matrix ordered ?

Comment: @msalvadores no there is no any order. it is just example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your L is constant size (4 elements, as you say), just compute its sum over all < n*m positions and find the maximum one.  Repeat for the 8 different orientations you could have.  That's O(nm) overall.

Comment: Omega(nm) is a trivial lower bound, you need to look at every element in the array.

Comment: This is correct for the problem as stated. If the L is constant size it is a trivial problem.

Comment: @hilal: Sometimes brute force is the only answer, in which case it's the right answer :)