# Finding a submatrix with largest sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a submatrix with the maximum possible sum in O(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116048/finding-a-submatrix-with-the-maximum-possible-sum-in-on2)

I have an NxN matrix. I want to find out an MxM submatrix, with largest sum of its elements, of the above matrix.

What is the efficient algorithm for this.

Comment: This is not necessarily a duplicate. The important difference is that in this simpler case the original matrix is square and the size of the matrix to be found is known in advance (unless M is unknown at the start, in which case they would be quite similar) That means that you only need to find the location, but not the shape of the inner matrix, simplifying the problem. With those limitations, this can be solved in quadratic time (see answer below), while the marked as duplicate cannot be solved in less than cubic time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an algorithm that runs in constant time when enlarging M and quadratic time when enlarging N.

First submatrix count as usual. Save the sum. Then move one row field right - the two MxM matrices overlap, so you can just just sum the two non overlaping columns. Save all the sums. Now you can choose the largest sum for the line.

Move to next line. Remember the saved sums? The MxM matrices of first and second lines overlap again, so you can just sum the first and the last lines of MxM matrices and compute first sum in second line.

Now move to the second sum of the second line. Do the same thing as above, but you find out that the last lines of first sum and the second sum in the second row overlap again.

I know it is kind of confusing, if you don't get it, let me know I will draw some picture of it. The algorithm is based on paper in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810657/fastest-code-c-c-to-select-the-median-in-a-set-of-27-floating-point-values/1413048#1413048).

EDIT: I know I promised picture, but this should be enough:

```
A  AB   AB   AB   AB   B
AC ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD BD
AC ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD BD
AC ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD BD
AC ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD BD
 C   CD   CD   CD   CD  D
```

These are four submatices, A, B, C, D, positioned like this:

```
AB
CD
```

First you count the sum of the A submatrix: sum(A). No optimizations here. Now you want to count the sum of B: sum(B). You can do the same as in A, but notice that A and B overlap. So you assign sum(A) to sum(B), count the sum of vertical vector `A AC AC AC AC` and substract if from sum(B), then count the sum of vertical vector `B BD BD BD BD` and add it to sum(B).

```
sum(B) = sum(A) - sum(A AC AC AC AC) + sum(B BD BD BD BD)
```

You have sum(B). Now you can continue and compute the whole first line of submatices.

Move to the second line: matices C and D. You don't have to sum the whole matice C, because in previous line, you saved sum(A). Notice they overlap again. You just need to add the difference between A and C:

```
//code (1)
subC = sum([A AB AB AB AB])   //as substract C
addC = sum([C CD CD CD CD])   //as add C
sum(C) = sum(A) - subC + addC
```

You have sum(C). Now you can get sum(D) like this:

```
//code (2)
subD = sum([AB AB AB AB B])    //as substract D
addD = sum([CD CD CD CD D])    //as add D
sum(D) = sum(B) - subD + addD
```

but compare subD vs. subC and addD vs addC. They overlap! So you can do it this way:

```
//code (3)
subD = subC - A + B //from subC substract value on A and add B to it
addD = addC - C + D //same as above
sum(D) = sum(B) - subD + addD
```

You see that instead of 25 aditions for comuting sum of one submatrix, we do 6. For every possible size of MxM, we have MxM aditions for first submatrix, M*2+2 aditions for first row and for first column and 6 aditions for the rest.

Comment: Yes, as you said I found it confusing..

Comment: `(N - M + 1) * (N - M + 1)` isn't linear...

Comment: The worst case is when `M=1`, and `N—>∞`. In that case you will have to compare NxN elements, and the best algorithm you can imagine cannot but at least read each element once. That means that the complexity cannot be linear in N, but quadratic. What you have described is a speedup for a general algorithm that would take it from N^2*M^2 (i.e. for each (N-M)^2 squares sum the (M^2) elements of the inner matrix) down to N^2 (each element in the outer matrix is counted only in a fixed number of inner matrices in and out of the row and column).

Comment: Fixed the linear time thing. I realized it when turned of the computer. Will post the image today.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I have voted to reopen the question, consider the comment above, you might want to change your vote to close.